# Issue in creating package.json using npm init

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, package.json

I am trying to create package.json file on compute engine vm instance using " npm init" command. But, its not getting executed.

```
$sudo pip install npm
Requirement already satisfied: npm in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: optional-django==0.1.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from npm)
$ init npm
Expected single character argument.
```

As per the reference materials, i could find above command only to create package.json but its not being executed.Tried with this as well :

```
$ npm init
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Can anyone help with any resolution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to why you're running `pip install npm` - pip is a Python "thing", and npm is a node.js "thing".  Why combine the two?

You should install npm like this:
`sudo apt-get install npm` , assuming this is a Linux instance.

Comment: sudo apt-get install npm does not work. $sudo apt-get install npm
sudo: apt-get: command not found
$ sudo apt-get-y update
sudo: apt-get-y: command not found. It is Linux instance (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 ) . Any further help ?

Comment: Ah, right - you can't use apt-get (OOB) on Red Hat.  You have to use "yum" to install packages.